# Игрок неправильно передвигается

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Я пишу онлайн игру по типу агарио. Код перемещения игрока я сделал таким:

```
function sq(x) { return x*x; }

var mX = playerMouse.x; // Координаты мышки по X
var mY = playerMouse.y; // Координаты мышки по Y
var mouseAngle = Math.atan2(player.mY, player.mX);
var mouseDist = Math.sqrt(sq(player.mX) + sq(player.mY));
player.vx = (mouseDist / config.maxspeed ) * Math.cos(mouseAngle) / config.maxspeed;
player.vy = (mouseDist / config.maxspeed ) * Math.sin(mouseAngle) / config.maxspeed;

if (player.vx > config.maxspeed) { player.vx = config.maxspeed + (player.vx - Math.floor(player.vx)) }
if (player.vx < -config.maxspeed) { player.vx = -config.maxspeed - (-player.vx + Math.floor(player.vx))}
if (player.vy > config.maxspeed) { player.vy = config.maxspeed + (player.vy - Math.floor(player.vy))}
if (player.vy < -config.maxspeed) { player.vy = -config.maxspeed - (-player.vy + Math.floor(player.vy))}

player.x += player.vx;
player.y += player.vy;
```

Но он двигается не совсем рядом с мышкой, иногда даже вверх направлен.
На скриншоте красным цветом обозначено направление мышки, синим - перемещение игрока. Как это исправить?

[image: Движение игрока]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вычисления вектора направления между игроком и мышью нужно использовать разности координат, иначе всегда получается направление из начала координат на мышь.

```
var mX = playerMouse.x - player.x; 
var mY = playerMouse.y - player.y;
```

Задание скорости в зависимости от расстояния:

```
speed = min(maxspeed, a * pow(mouseDist, pwr));
player.vx = speed* Math.cos(mouseAngle);
player.vy = speed* Math.sin(mouseAngle);
```

Здесь `a` - некий коэффициент. В `pow` используется нужная степень `pwr`.
Например, для имитации гравитации - `pwr = -2`.

Если нужна прямая пропорциональность (чем дальше - тем быстрее), то `pwr = 1`, линейный закон

```
speed = min(maxspeed, a * mouseDist);
```

Оценка `a` - для линейного закона на максимальном расстоянии - скажем, 1000 пикселов, скорость должна быть `maxspeed`:

```
maxspeed = a * 1000
1.5 = a * 1000
a = 0.0015
```

Comment: Проблема в скорости, ведь если игрок будет медленнее максимальной скорости, все будет в норме.

Comment: Раздельно изменение компонентов скорости исказит направление. Но я пока не понял, по какому принципу задаётся скорость

Comment: Если удалить строки с if, то он будет лететь строго к мышке, и чем дальше от игрока курсор, тем быстрее.

Comment: Нет, Вы объясните - какой закон нужен для скорости в зависимости от расстояния?  То, что я сейчас дописал - подходит?

Comment: Подходит, летит нормально! Но есть одно но: при pwr = 1, a = 2, и maxspeed = 1.5 - игрок летит с одной скоростью несмотря на дальность. То-есть, скорость не меняется. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Нужно чтобы если ближе к игроку, то скорость снижается, вплоть до остановки.

Comment: `cкорость не меняется`  Коэффициент `а` слишком большой, для пробы уменьшите в 10, 100, 10000 раз

Comment: Если линейный закон подходит, то pow можно убрать, `speed = min(maxspeed, a * mouseDist);`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, a = 0.035 подходит отлично!